# How to clear ClientPeoplePicker field from a button click event handler?

Tags: clientpeoplepicker

I am building a custom form that includes a ClientPeoplePicker control.

[image: screenshot]

When the user press the **Clear** button, all the fields in the forms should be reset to empty/initial status. I can do this for all the fields except the ClientPeoplePicker one.

Following is the current handler I am using for the button click event:

```
 protected void ClearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     txtEmpFName.Text = string.Empty;
     txtEmpEGN.Text = string.Empty;
     dropDep.SelectedIndex = 0;
     dtStartDate.SelectedDate = new DateTime(0);

     PickerEntity picker = (PickerEntity)peoplePicker.ResolvedEntities[0];
     SPUser userInstance = oSPWeb.EnsureUser(picker.Key);
     userInstance.Name = string.Empty; // <------| This is my problem...
 }
```

As a reference, this is the relevant code for the picker control:

```
<td>
    <SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker
         Required="true"
         ValidationEnabled="true"
         ID="peoplePicker"
         runat="server"
         InitialHelpText="Please, insert a valid User!"
         VisibleSuggestions="3"
         Width="180px"
         Rows="1"
         AllowMultipleEntities="false"
         CssClass="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" />
 </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PeoplePickerControlName.AllEntities.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this single line of code which will clear the `PeoplePicker` field.

```
peoplePicker.CommaSeparatedAccounts = null;
```

You don't need below lines in your code to clear `peoplepicker`

```
PickerEntity picker = (PickerEntity)peoplePicker.ResolvedEntities[0];
SPUser userInstance = oSPWeb.EnsureUser(picker.Key);
userInstance.Name = string.Empty;
```

Comment: I don't have a property CommaSeparatedAccounts ...

Comment: Error 1 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ClientPeoplePicker' does not contain a definition for 'CommaSeparatedAccounts' and no extension method 'CommaSeparatedAccounts' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ClientPeoplePicker' could be found

Comment: My bad, i thought its PeopleEditor control you are using.

Comment: I have a SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker Controll

Comment: anyone has answer to this question?Please help

Answer (score 1):

you can give a try

```
PeopleEditor.Accounts.Clear();
PeopleEditor.Entities.Clear();
PeopleEditor.ResolvedEntities.Clear();
```

works on fly.

Comment: I have a SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker Controll

Comment: I believe Hardik is using your ID on the ClientPeoplePicker control. This should work.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: You can check this link http://www.sharemuch.com/2011/12/04/how-to-address-sharepoint-2010-people-editor-issue-not-clearing/